# Modify sync function to async function in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, async-await

I am trying to modify this function into async/await. How do I make it?

```
  public getProduct(id: number){
      this.subscriptions.add(
        this.productService.getProduct(id).subscribe(((res) => {
          return res
        }),
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        })
      );
    
  }
```

Comment: If you're using the this.subscriptions.add () method, you don't need to use an async / await function. You can use this.subscription.subscribe () whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific need of using async, await ; I would suggest this implementation :

```
// Warning, probable anti-pattern below
async getProduct(id: number)) {
    const result = await this.productService.getProduct(id).toPromise();

}
```